# AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'tranform'

Tags: python, machine-learning, transform, attributeerror, tfidfvectorizer

I keep on getting this error for this code,

x_predict = ['facebook.com', 'google.com/search=phish', 'wikipedia.com']

**x_predict = vectorizer.tranform(x_predict)**

y_predict = lgr.predict(x_predict)

print(y_predict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is spelling error:

Use `transform` instead of `tranform`

```
x_predict = vectorizer.transform(x_predict)
```

Comment: thank you. my bad...

Comment: @Lunatic Welcome to Stack Overflow; if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it.